# Binding datagrid to datatable

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm fairly new to VB.net/MVVM/WPF/xaml and I'm learning to use the datagrid. I have successfully bound it to an observable collection but want to bind it to a datatable. I have looked at a number of answers on SO but cannot understand most of them. I have attempted to try a number of various ways after reading answers to other peoples questions but still can't seem to make it work after 4 evenings trying! I have got to the point of being able to add rows (no data in them) but no columns or data in columns. Another post suggested creating the table then binding it, another setting the datatable to null (created an error) prior, another who had the same issue but no answer was presented and another that said columns needed headers first. I'm a bit confused.

Other controls bind ok so I assume it's not that and I'm probably making a fairly stupid error. I would like to keep it using bindings and not referencing the datagrid directly which I have seen in other answers. Also, I would like to avoid Linq at the moment as just learning WPF is a bit of steep curve.

Current code;

Mainwindow.xaml.vb, Public Sub New;

```
Me.DataContext = myModelView
```

Binding;

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding dtCharDG, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0,152,0,251" />
```

Binding Property (dt should be dv);

```
    Public Property dtCharDG() As DataView
        Get
            Return dtCharDGValue
        End Get
        Set(dtCharDGValue As DataView)
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property
```

Call, just dumped in a button at the moment;

```
        Dim dtCharDGTemp As New DataTable
        CreateCharGrid("Hello World", dtCharDGTemp)

        dtCharDG = dtCharDGTemp.DefaultView
```

Sub;

```
    Public Sub CreateCharGrid(ByVal CharSet As String, ByRef dtToFill As DataTable)

        'Dim  As New DataTable
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
        Dim workColumn As New DataColumn
        Dim workRow As DataRow

        x = Len(CharSet)

        For y = 0 To x - 1
            workColumn = New DataColumn()
            dtToFill.Columns.Add(workColumn)
        Next


        workRow = dtToFill.NewRow()
        For y = 0 To x - 1
            workRow(y) = y + 1
        Next

        dtToFill.Rows.Add(workRow)

    End Sub
```

I've messed around with it so much there's probably quite a lot to fix and I've just got lost. The intention is to fill a datagrid with the characters from string in separate columns in the second row and in the top row an integer per column showing where it is in the string.

Any help gratefully received from a relative newbie.

Comment: If you're new to vb.net, I suggest you learn c#.net. Especially if you're going to ask questions in fora. Far more devs use c#.

Comment: I agree but I learnt VB6 in school so was familiar with VB. I bought a book on C# but paled at learning WPF plus C# plus XAML all at the same time. Will convert to C# when I'm comfortable with WPF and XAML!

Comment: I did vb3 through 6 and started .net using VB. Switched over in 2005. Took a week to pick up enough to be comfortable, fwiw.  Lot to learn in Wpf. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just missing DataTable.Rows.Add()

See here for more info...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-data-to-a-datatable

If you are wanting columns to be numbers and 1st row to be letters in the string try this change

```
        For y = 0 To x - 1
            workColumn = New DataColumn(y.ToString())
            dtToFill.Columns.Add(workColumn)
        Next


        workRow = dtToFill.NewRow()
        For y = 0 To x - 1
            workRow(y) = CharSet.Substring(y, 1)
        Next

        dtToFill.Rows.Add(workRow)
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks. I've tried that before and have modified the code as above. No errors and no data. Still one blank column

Comment: if you are wanting numbers as columns and the first row as letters of the string try this...        For y = 0 To x - 1
            workColumn = New DataColumn(y.ToString())
            dtToFill.Columns.Add(workColumn)
        Next


        workRow = dtToFill.NewRow()
        For y = 0 To x - 1
            workRow(y) = CharSet.Substring(y, 1)
        Next

        dtToFill.Rows.Add(workRow)